# Hangman game in java without arrays

Tags: java

The goal of this code is to create a basic hangman game. Everything works fine up until the last step. After the user guesses all the letters it's supposed to display `"You guessed it"`, but the loop seems to execute one extra time. I tried changing the loop code to:
`while(guessedLetters < asteriskAmount - 1)` but that just made the loop end one time too early.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecretPhrase {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char userChoice;
    String secretPhrase = "GO TEAM";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String hint = "G* T***";
    StringBuilder secretWord = new StringBuilder(hint);

    System.out.println("The hint is " + hint); 

    System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
    userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0)); //Taking the input and turning to uppercase for comparing purposes

    int asteriskAmount = hint.length() - 1; // "-1" for the space.
    int guessedLetters = 2; // for the 'G' and the 'T' that are already displayed.

    while(guessedLetters < asteriskAmount) {
        boolean isInPhrase = checkLetter(userChoice, secretPhrase);
        if(isInPhrase) { // if the guessed letter is a letter in the phrase...
            int position = getPosition(userChoice, secretPhrase); 
            secretWord.setCharAt(position, userChoice);
            hint = secretWord.toString();
            guessedLetters++; 
            System.out.println(secretWord);
            System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
            userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That letter is not in the phrase. Please try again >>> ");
            userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You got it! The secret word is " + secretWord);


}
public static boolean checkLetter(char userChoice, String secretPhrase) {
    boolean isInPhrase = false;
    int amountOfLetters = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < secretPhrase.length(); x++) {
        if(userChoice != secretPhrase.charAt(x)) {
            isInPhrase = false;
        }
        else {
            isInPhrase = true;
            amountOfLetters++;
        }
    }
    if(amountOfLetters >= 1) {
        isInPhrase = true;
    }
    return isInPhrase;
}
public static int getPosition(char userChoice, String secretPhrase) {
    int position;
    int x = 0;
    while(userChoice != secretPhrase.charAt(x)) {
        x++;
    }
    position = x;
    return position;
}
}
```

This is my output:

```
The hint is G* T***
Please guess a letter
**o**
GO T***
Please guess a letter
**e**
GO TE**
Please guess a letter
**a**
GO TEA*
Please guess a letter
**m**
GO TEAM
Please guess a letter
**a**
You got it! The secret word is GO TEAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines from before the loop

```
System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
```

Now inside the loop, move those same lines to the beginning of the loop.

```
while(guessedLetters < asteriskAmount) {
        System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
        userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    boolean isInPhrase = checkLetter(userChoice, secretPhrase);
    if(isInPhrase) { // if the guessed letter is a letter in the phrase...
        int position = getPosition(userChoice, secretPhrase); 
        secretWord.setCharAt(position, userChoice);
        hint = secretWord.toString();
        guessedLetters++; 
        System.out.println(secretWord);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That letter is not in the phrase. Please try again >>> ");
        userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Edit: To check for multiple instances of the chosen letter without using arrays, try using this in place of your replacement code

```
for(int r=0; r<secretPhrase.length(); r++){
    if(secretPhrase.charAt(r) == userChoice){
        secretWord.setCharAt(r, userChoice);
        guessedLetters++;
    }
}
```

With this, you should no longer need the `getPosition` method or `position` variable.

**full loop with suggested alterations**

```
while(guessedLetters < asteriskAmount) {
        System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
        userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    boolean isInPhrase = checkLetter(userChoice, secretPhrase);
    if(isInPhrase) { // if the guessed letter is a letter in the phrase...
        for(int r=0; r<secretPhrase.length(); r++){
            if(secretPhrase.charAt(r) == userChoice){
                secretWord.setCharAt(r, userChoice);
                guessedLetters++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(secretWord);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That letter is not in the phrase. Please try again >>> ");
        userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. How would I replace the asterisks with the letters if there is more than one occurrence without arrays? I was thinking along the lines of, instead of the `checkLetter` method returning a `boolean`, maybe it can return an `int` value that tells me how many time that letter occurs, and then make some kind of loop that would replace the asterisks with the letter. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply sooner, I was on the road. I have updated my answer to achieve the same result without using arrays. Give it a look and see what you think :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just wanted to to point out that you need to add `()`s in the `for(int r......length())`

Comment: Ah I get that confused a lot since arrays also have a `.length` but without the `()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always asking again after incrementing `guessedLetters`.  So it's always going to ask one extra time.  Try reordering things, for example:

```
//System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
//userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0)); //Taking the input and turning to uppercase for comparing purposes

final int asteriskAmount = hint.length() - 1; // "-1" for the space.
int guessedLetters = 2; // for the 'G' and the 'T' that are already displayed.

while (guessedLetters < asteriskAmount) {
    System.out.println(secretWord);
    System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
    userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));

    final boolean isInPhrase = checkLetter(userChoice, secretPhrase);
    if (isInPhrase) { // if the guessed letter is a letter in the phrase...
        final int position = getPosition(userChoice, secretPhrase);
        secretWord.setCharAt(position, userChoice);
        hint = secretWord.toString();
        guessedLetters++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("That letter is not in the phrase. Please try again >>> ");
        userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    }

    System.out.println(guessedLetters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the user input inside your while loop. What was happening was that at the final loop, you go through validating the user input, and then ask for another user input at the end of the loop. The game tries and finish but before it can finish it has to go through that last user input in the `while`. I always try and put my user input at the beginning of the loop so stuff like this does not happen. Hope this helps!

```
System.out.println("The hint is " + hint); 

//Move the 2 lines below inside your loop
//System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
//userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0)); //Taking the input and turning to uppercase for comparing purposes

int asteriskAmount = hint.length() - 1; // "-1" for the space.
int guessedLetters = 2; // for the 'G' and the 'T' that are already displayed.

while(guessedLetters < asteriskAmount) {

    //Moved from above
    System.out.println(secretWord);
    System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
    userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));

    boolean isInPhrase = checkLetter(userChoice, secretPhrase);
    if(isInPhrase) { // if the guessed letter is a letter in the phrase...
        int position = getPosition(userChoice, secretPhrase); 
        secretWord.setCharAt(position, userChoice);
        hint = secretWord.toString();
        guessedLetters++; 

        //These are not needed any more
        //System.out.println(secretWord);
        //System.out.println("Please guess a letter");
        //userChoice = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
    }
```